# Boostrap Data On Start-Up , Spring MVC, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'am working on J2EE spring Mvc Based App with hibernate And Spring Security, And I want to bootstrap some data on Start-up ( one and only one time during the app life Cycle ),  I'm Using hbm2ddl to create tables after launching the application, but they are empty, so I need to add instances to the database  ( Username , password ... ) So I can test my App on development mode. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file called `import.sql` in the root of your classpath, Hibernate [will execute it](http://in.relation.to/9081.lace) on application startup.

Please note that it is a Hibernate feature and thus not portable between persistence providers.